# Stirling numbers of the second kind: a recurrence relation.

Tags: combinatorics, semigroups, stirling-numbers

This is Exercise 1.9.15 of Howie's *"Fundamentals of Semigroup Theory"*.

> Let $X$ be a finite set with $n$ elements and let $S(n, r)$ (for $0\le r\le n$) be the number of equivalences $\rho$ on $X$ such that $\lvert X/\rho\rvert=r$. Show that
>   $$S(n, 1)=S(n, n)=1\tag{1}$$ and
>   $$S(n, r)=S(n-1, r-1)+rS(n-1, r)\tag{2}$$ for $(2\le r\le n-1)$.

### My Attempt:

Let $\mathcal{E}_X$ be the set of equivalences on $X$.

For $(1)$, we have that
$$\begin{align}
S(n, 1)&=\lvert\{\rho\in \mathcal{E}_X : \lvert X/\rho\rvert=1\}\rvert \\
&\stackrel{(?)}{=}\lvert\{X\times X\}\rvert \\
&=1
\end{align}$$ and

$$\begin{align}
S(n, n)&=\lvert\{\rho\in \mathcal{E}_X : \lvert X/\rho\rvert=n\}\rvert \\
&\stackrel{(?)}{=}\lvert\{\operatorname{id}_X\}\rvert \\
&=1.
\end{align}$$

---

I'm stuck showing $(2)$.

### Thoughts:

I suppose showing $(2)$ is a matter of induction on $n$ but I don't know where to start.

Please help :)

Comment: It maybe helpful to think of an equivalence on $ X $ as a partition of $ X $. You can make a partition of $ X $ into $ r $ subsets as follows: Fix an element $ x $ of $ X $. Then either partition the other $ n- 1 $ into $ r-1 $ subsets and put $ x $ into his own subset, or, partition the other $ n-1 $ into $ r $ subsets and put $ x $ into one of those $ r $ subsets. These are the two terms in the recursion relation.

Comment: @user81327 That should be an answer.

Comment: @user81327 I can see how that's a comment if you'll give an answer with more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments:

> It maybe helpful to think of an equivalence on $ X $ as a partition of $ X $. You can make a partition of $ X $ into $ r $ subsets as follows: Fix an element $ x $ of $ X $. Then either partition the other $ n- 1 $ into $ r-1 $ subsets and put $ x $ into his own subset, or, partition the other $ n-1 $ into $ r $ subsets and put $ x $ into one of those $ r $ subsets. These are the two terms in the recursion relation.

Comment: @user81327 Here :)

Comment: Thank you :) I left it as a comment because I didn't want to give a full answer; I figured you'd fill in the details with the hint.